# Arch Linux not waking up from suspend when USB C hub is plugged in

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, nvidia, suspend, freeze

When the USB C hub is not plugged in, suspend works fine and I can wake up with the laptop keyboard or the power button. However, when I plug in the hub, none of the devices work for waking up the laptop. The laptop's internal keyboard and power button do nothing, and even by enabling the keyboard attached to the hub as a wakeup device, it still does not work.

Here are some info about the hardware:
Laptop mode: Asus Zenbook 14 UX435EG 
CPU: Intel Core i7 1165G7 11th Gen with Intel Iris Xe GPU 
Discrete GPU: Nvidia MX450 
Ram: 16GB LPDDR4X

And some info about the system: 
Kernel: 5.16.2-arch1-1 
Distro: Arch Linux 
Init system: Systemd 
GPU Drivers: i965, nvidia (proprietary driver) 
Graphical Server: Xorg 
Window Manager: Qtile 
Lock: xsecurelock 
Bootloader: Grub 
Kernel parameters: `loglevel=3 mem_sleep_default=deep resume=UUID=04481cca-5956-4100-a12a-207a3c942279` 
Sleep state: `mem` 
Sleep mode: `deep`

lsusb when the hub is unplugged:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:56eb IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa61 Areson Technology Corp Elecom Co., Ltd MR-K013 Multicard Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb when the hub is plugged in:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:56eb IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa61 Areson Technology Corp Elecom Co., Ltd MR-K013 Multicard Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`/proc/acpi/wakeup` is the same no matter if the hub is plugged in or not:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PEG1      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG3      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG0      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:57:00.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0
RP05      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.4
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:58:00.0
PEGA      S4    *disabled
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
XDCI      S4    *disabled
HDAS      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3
CNVW      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.3
TXHC      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.0
TDM0      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.2
TDM1      S3    *disabled
TRP0      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
TRP1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
PXSX      S4    *disabled
TRP2      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
TRP3      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
AWAC      S4    *enabled   platform:ACPI000E:00
```

I tried `linux-lts` and there was no difference. I also tried with the `nouveau` drivers. Also, I tried both early KMS and late KMS for the GPU drivers and nothing changed. I tried disabling `nvidia-suspend.service` and even removing its symlink. Changing `deep` to `s2idle` which was the default mode brought another problem. It suspends fine, but when I wake up the device, there is a blank screen with a solid cursor. If I suspend from a tty, the tty comes back frozen.

I tried with kernel 5.11 on a Ubuntu live USB and both deep and s2idle worked fine whether the hub was plugged in or no, however, I can't tell if it was due to a specific ubuntu config, or the kernel version.

last lines of Journalctl log (deep sleep):

```
Jan 27 17:34:05 mahan-lap systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jan 27 17:34:05 mahan-lap systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Jan 27 17:34:05 mahan-lap wpa_supplicant[961]: p2p-dev-wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jan 27 17:34:05 mahan-lap wpa_supplicant[961]: p2p-dev-wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jan 27 17:34:05 mahan-lap wpa_supplicant[961]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jan 27 17:34:05 mahan-lap wpa_supplicant[961]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jan 27 17:34:05 mahan-lap systemd-sleep[13029]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
```

dmesg (journalctl -k):

```
an 27 17:33:40 mahan-lap kernel: audit: type=1105 audit(1643292220.625:158): pid=12605 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_systemd_home,pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_p>
Jan 27 17:33:53 mahan-lap kernel: audit: type=1106 audit(1643292233.112:159): pid=12605 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_systemd_home,pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_>
Jan 27 17:33:53 mahan-lap kernel: audit: type=1104 audit(1643292233.112:160): pid=12605 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_faillock acct="root>
Jan 27 17:34:05 mahan-lap kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1643292245.471:161): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/sys>
Jan 27 17:34:05 mahan-lap kernel: wlan0: deauthenticating from 10:27:f5:84:23:17 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

I can identify whether the device is still asleep or frozen after wakeup by the laptop's power LED. With deep sleep, the LED still shows suspend state, meaning the device is not make up.